# If clauses inside makefile produces erros

Tags: makefile

I have the following part of a `Makefile`

```
#.SILENT:
#.PHONY:
SHELL     := /bin/bash
################################################################
## Colordefinition
################################################################
NO_COLOR    = \x1b[0m
OK_COLOR    = \x1b[32;01m
ERROR_COLOR = \x1b[31;01m

%.pdf: %.tex
    NAME=`basename $< .tex` ;\
    echo -e "\t$(OK_COLOR)Typesetting $$NAME$(NO_COLOR)" ;\
    pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=nonstopmode $< > /dev/null ;\
    if [ $$? = 0 ] ; then \
      echo -e "\t$(OK_COLOR)compilation in draftmode without erros$(NO_COLOR)" ;\
      pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $< > /dev/null ;\
      if [ -e $$NAME.glo ] ; then \
        echo -e "$(OK_COLOR)Typesetting $$NAME.glo$(NO_COLOR)" ;\
        makeindex -s gglo.ist -o $$NAME.gls $$NAME.glo ;\
      fi ;\
      if [ -e $$NAME.idx ] ; then \
        echo -e "$(OK_COLOR)Typesetting $$NAME.idx$(NO_COLOR)" ;\
        makeinde -s gind.ist $$NAME.idx ;\
      fi ;\ 
    else \
      echo -e "\t$(ERROR_COLOR)compilation in draftmode with erros$(NO_COLOR)" ;\
      exit 0;\
    fi ;\
    echo -e "\t$(OK_COLOR)Typesetting $$NAME finished $(NO_COLOR)" ;\
```

The makefile doens't work and I can't find the error.

My goal is to type:

```
make test.pdf
```

The following example can be used for testing (test.tex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

How must the Makefile improve?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that typing `make test.pdf` works perfectly. Might not produce any useful results, though, but just typing `make test.pdf` will certainly work. So, please define what "does not work" means in your case, and what "work" should be.

Comment: @thiton: Does it really work for you? I get the error `/bin/bash: -c: Zeile 14: Syntax Fehler: Unerwartetes Dateiende.
make: *** [test.pdf] Fehler 1` Try in English: `/bin/bash: -c: line 14: Syntax Error: unexpected file end.
make: *** [test.pdf] Fehler 1`

Comment: Now, that's an error message. Include it into your post next time. And use `LC_ALL=en_US make` for those speaking no German.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a superfluous space after the backslash in the line 14 (`fi ;\`) directly before the `else`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Only before the '\'. If in doubt, follow bmargulies excellent advice and write the shell script into a file of its own.

Answer (score 4):

This level of complexity in a make command is a recipe for pain and suffering. You will find your life much more pleasant if you take that giant concatenation of commands and move it to a .sh file. Then test and debug the .sh file, and then make a simple makefile that simply runs the .sh file. If someone else cares to read your makefile with a fine tooth comb and find your particular problem, more power to them.

If you need to debug this, make a copy. Delete the second half of the script. See if it works. If not, keep deleting until you isolate the problem. Though the answer that pointed out the extra space is probably spot-on.

Comment: I understand your point of view. The makefile should be uploaded to CTAN and the "End user" should only run make all. At the moment I am trying to simplify the currecnt Makefile on github: https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: I was inspired by this Makefile: https://github.com/uktug/latex-beginners-course/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Well, in that case, note that the error message indicates a missing 'end' of something. Reduce by binary search.